# How to implement your own DFT in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, fft

I am trying to implement the Fourier transfer of my own in Open CV python. To start with the theoretical part I have understood the formula for computing the Fourier transform. The first step is take DFT/FFT of an image, I am finding it difficult to comprehend how the go with the coding part.

Comment: You can use `numpy.fft2`  or you can just run your own. A 2D FFT is the nothing but taking the FFTs of each row, then taking the FFTs of each column of the previous. So if you want to use FFTW (better for non power of 2 runlengths) instead of numpy's FFT that would be the way to go.

Comment: Have a look at some open source implementations and try to understand what's going on. Then you should know what to do.